# How to limit all variables in one row that the sum is 100%?

Tags: excel, vba, random, sum

does anyone has an idea how to command that the sum of each row is always 100%? Thant includes that the random variables within the row have to know the values of the cells in the same row or?

[image]

```
    Sub Randomm()
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction, rng As Range, zum As Single, i As Integer
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set rng = Range("F6:R50")
    Dim totalRow As Single
    
    rng.Formula = "=RAND()"
    rng.Value = rng.Value
    zum = wf.sum(rng)
    For i = 6 To 50
        Cells(i, 6).Value = Cells(i, 13).Value / zum
        
    Next i
    rng.NumberFormat = "0.00%"

    
    
    End Sub

    Function GenerateRandomNumbers(ByVal size As Integer) As Variant
    
    ReDim vals(1 To size) As Single
    Dim idx As Integer
    Dim sum As Single
    
    For idx = 1 To size
        vals(idx) = Rnd
        sum = sum + vals(idx)
    Next idx
    
    For idx = 1 To size
        vals(idx) = vals(idx) / sum
    Next idx
    
    GenerateRandomNumbers = vals
    
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could sample from [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution), which returns array of values summed to 1. Then you could scale it to 100% or to whatever value you need.

I have little knowledge about how VBA works, so this is just sketch of the code

```
Function GenerateRandomNumbers(ByVal size As Integer) As Variant

ReDim vals(1 To size) As Single
Dim idx As Integer
Dim sum As Single

For idx = 1 To size
    vals(idx) = -Log(1.0-Rnd) 'sample as exponential
    sum = sum + vals(idx)     'find total sum
Next idx

For idx = 1 To size
    vals(idx) = vals(idx) / sum 'normalization
Next idx

GenerateRandomNumbers = vals

End Function
```

Comment: for a little knowledge this seems quite good! See my answer...do you have a math background? I try myself for 6 month with VBA now and this is for now? Unreachable. So if you say you just know a little....then it hurts :P. Do you have any recommendation regarding the knowledge you earnt? Staistics, Math, Programming? Again thanks a lot.

Comment: @Severin What is the purpose of -Log(1.0-Rnd) and why is it to be preferred to just Rnd in this application?

Comment: @NicholasHunter This is part of Dirichlet sampling. For values of alpha equal to 1 (see Wiki on Dirichlet sampling), it amounts to sampling from exponential and normalizing, and  `-Log(1.0-Rnd)` is what exponential sampling is. I used `1-Rnd` instead of just Rnd because Rnd is defined in [0...1) interval, so we avoid potential Log(0) case.

Comment: @NicholasHunter Concerning Dirichlet, it is well-known distribution which guaranteed to sum to 1, has well defined marginal distributions, momenta, entropy, etc. If you want to use just Rnd, go for it, but what kind of distribution is it? What would be marginals? Could you say anything about mean value? About variance?

Comment: @Severin Thank you for your response. If you don't know ahead of time the value of n, I don't understand how to guarantee that f(1), f(2), ..., f(n) will sum to 1? Rnd is a scalar. Were you assuming that Rnd is a vector?

Comment: @NicholasHunter You generate `n` number from exponential, find sum, divide by sum and return. It guarantees that later they add to 1. You have to know the size, and it is the parameter in the function in OP question. I assume he knows number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

For all who have the same question at any time, the Dirichlet Distribution function by @Severin Pappadeux works with the Sub below mentioned (reference: sub Solution by another user from stackoverflow)

```
    Sub Random3()
 
    Dim row As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim thirteenRandomNumbersWhichSumToOne As Variant
 
    With Worksheets("Optimierung2")
        
        For row = 11 To 55
        
            thirteenRandomNumbersWhichSumToOne = GenerateRandomNumbers(13)
            
            For col = 6 To 18 ' F to R
                
                .Cells(row, col).Value = thirteenRandomNumbersWhichSumToOne(col - 5)
                .Cells(row, col).NumberFormat = "0%"
            
            Next col

            .Cells(row, 19).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC6:RC18)"
            .Cells(row, 19).NumberFormat = "0%"
            
        Next row
        
    End With

 End Sub
 
 Function GenerateRandomNumbers(ByVal size As Integer) As Variant

ReDim vals(1 To size) As Single
Dim idx As Integer
Dim sum As Single

For idx = 1 To size
    vals(idx) = -Log(1# - Rnd) 'sample as exponential
    sum = sum + vals(idx)     'find total sum
Next idx

For idx = 1 To size
    vals(idx) = vals(idx) / sum 'normalization
Next idx

GenerateRandomNumbers = vals

End Function
```